# Lost power to sub panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have a double 50 breaker in service panel and wires go to power my sub panel .  Always had 120 volts at hots on double 50 and 120 volts coming into each leg in sub panel.
A couple guys had to mess around with things.  Now I have 120 volts on each hot in service panel but power into sub panel is 79 volts on one and 54 volts on other   Any idea what they could have done?

Comment: Ask them not us. How are you getting those readings?

Comment: Is this feeder feeding a detached outbuilding, or something in the same house as the main panel?

Comment: The sub panel is for the well..  Both main and sub panels are on a pole.  Main on one side.  Sub on other.  About 15 inches of wire from main to feeder of sub panel.

Comment: Obviously you have a way you like to measure voltage, but there is more than one way.  Which do you use?

Answer (score 2):

### They damaged the feeder, or a connection to it

It seems like whatever those blokes were doing damaged the feeder somehow; most likely, this is at one end, and can be fixed by reterminating the wires (with the feeder breaker in the main panel OFF, and using an inch-pound torque wrench to tighten the connection setscrews to the torque on the breaker and panel labels).  If that doesn't fix it, then you'll need to find and repair where the feeder wiring was damaged.

Comment: Jack - I did ask them.  They said "Nothing.". They have been delaying all the work I try to do.  I use my multimeter.  I believe in testing before jumping in blindly.

Comment: @IdaHensley -- how long's the run out to the wellhead itself?

Comment: Cops often say they hate co-incidences. Me too ("No mam, we're not the police, we're musicians" ....from a scene in from Blues Brothers) couldn't resist! . But that this happened while you were getting work done says a lot. Is the sub-panel fed from the main panel or directly from the meter?  I don't know why you'd need a sub-panel for the well pump, normally a single breaker would do the job.   The OP said they "messed around with stuff"....we'll need a better description.  *WARNING:* you area dealing with REAL POWER in panels. If you try anything yourself, be super careful.